# Checkbox form on Next.js and Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, checkbox, next.js

I am working on a projet with `Next.js` and `Typescript`. I have a form and it is the first time working with `Typescript` and the checkbox type. I am having issues trying to get all the values of the checkboxes, adding if it is true or deleting if it is false. Also, I tried the spread operator but it breaks the code. This is the code:

States:

```
const [callTime, setCallTime] = useState<any>('');
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

Array:

```
const preferredTime = [
  {
    time: 'Before 9am',
  },
  {
    time: '9am to 12pm',
  },
  {
    time: '12pm to 3pm',
  },
  {
    time: 'After 3pm',
  },
];
```

Handler:

```
const onChangeCheckBox = (e: { target: { checked: boolean; value: React.SetStateAction<string>; }; }) => {
    setIsChecked(() => e.target.checked);
    // setIsChecked(() => !isChecked);
    setCallTime(e.target.value)
    console.log('radio', e.target.value);
    console.log('radio', e.target.checked);
}
```

return:

```
                    <p>Preferred call back time</p>
                    <div className={styles.radioGroup}>
                      {preferredTime.map((item, index) => (
                        <div key={index} className={styles.radios}>
                          <label htmlFor={item.time} className={styles.checkLabel}>{item.time}
                            <input
                                type="checkbox" 
                                value={item.time}
                                name="time" 
                                onChange={onChangeCheckBox}
                                id={item.time}
                                // checked={item.checked}
                                />
                            <span className={styles.checkSpan}></span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
```

This is a [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-curran-th7cud?file=/src/App.tsx) with the whole code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you wanted to do is this: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-resonance-e4bnyc?file=/src/App.tsx

I replaced the string in your callTime state by an array of object containing `{time: string, isChecked: boolean}`
Thanks to this you can easily manage the check status of each entry in the array. So with this, I put the `checked={item.isChecked}` in the map of your JSX

Comment: Thanks Leo, it works like a charm. I have a question that if you could help me with it I would much appreaciate it. What would be the type of callTime? There is any and it works, but just wondering if you know it.

Comment: Your welcome, I'm glad that it helped you ! The type of callTimes is ```{time: string, isChecked: boolean}[]``` because when I initialize the state I map on ```preferredTime``` and I append the property ```isChecked``` so it returns a list with the time (from the ```preferredTime``` object) + the isChecked

Comment: Thanks Leo for the explanation and the help.